# Use one template for one-dimensional array and three-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a template that uses a three-dimensional array to find the maximum. The crux of the problem is that this template must find the maximum in a one-dimensional array. We add a question with a char variable, if question = '1' = three-dimensional, if 2, then one-dimensional.

l need use template T2 for one dimensional and thee dimensional it depends of question(char)

```
T2 maxShablon2(T2 ***arr, const int n) {
    int max = arr[0][0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
                if (arr[i][j][k] > max) {
                    max = arr[i][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << " Our max: " << max;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66144512/edit) your question to clarify what it is your asking? If there is an issue with the code you've written, please describe the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

```
template<std::size_t N>
using count = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

template<class T>
constexpr T maxOver( count<0> unused, T t, int n ) {
  return t;
}
template<std::size_t depth, class Ptr>
constexpr auto maxOver( count<depth>, Ptr* t, int n ) {
  auto max = maxOver( count<depth-1>{}, t[0], n );
  for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    auto candidate = maxOver( count<depth-1>{}, t[i], n );
    if (candidate > max)
      max = candidate;
  }
  return max;
}
```

now,

```
constexpr int arr[100] = {1,2,3,0};
constexpr int arr_max = maxOver( count<1>{}, arr, 100 );
static_assert(arr_max == 3);
constexpr int arr3[5][5][5] = {{{1,-1,7},{2,3,4}},{{3},{4,5,9}}};
constexpr int arr3_max = maxOver( count<3>{}, arr3, 5 );
static_assert(arr3_max == 9);
```

[passes (Live example)](https://godbolt.org/z/e7qE7n).